# Diffrence between Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I started working with Ajax, and I'm listening tutorials on one tutorial i see the code like:

```
     $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

on other cases i see XMLHttPRequest done in javascript can someone tell me the diffrence between two? Beacuse its confusing listening one tutorial that tells you one thing and other second thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery wraps the use of XMLHttPRequest  with his $.get request (etc.)
So bassicly you are using the same method of Ajax.

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to google that diffrence but no such look, really was confused. 
So using jquery version is a bit easier?

Comment: Easier is in the eyes of the beholder